# Multiple Language Binding ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, localization

I want to change my single language project into multiple language, so I use ResourceDictionary to do it like this:

**XAML**

```
    <Button Content="{DynamicResource LanguageSetting}" Click="btn_LanguageSetting_Click"/>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    public static string windowCurrentLanguageFile = "Language/en.xaml";
    private void btn_LanguageSetting_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        windowCurrentLanguageFile = windowCurrentLanguageFile == "Language/en.xaml"
            ? "Language/ch.xaml"
            : "Language/en.xaml";

        var rd = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(windowCurrentLanguageFile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) };

        if (this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Count == 0)
            this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
        else
            this.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0] = rd;
    }
```

This works fine for me. But I have an `ItemsControl`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemOperate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:SelectableViewModel}">
                <Border x:Name="Border" Padding="0,8,0,8" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Checkerz" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ToggleButton VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                      Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignActionLightToggleButton}"
                                      Content="{Binding Code}" />
                        <StackPanel Margin="8 0 0 0" Grid.Column="7">
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignSelection}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Which Binding to the **ViewModel** like this:

```
public class SelectableViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (_isSelected == value) return;
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private char _code;
    public char Code
    {
        get { return _code; }
        set
        {
            if (_code == value) return;
            _code = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value) return;
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _description;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set
        {
            if (_description == value) return;
            _description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _itemOperate = CreateData();
    }

    private static ObservableCollection<SelectableViewModel> CreateData()
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<SelectableViewModel>
            {
                new SelectableViewModel
                {
                    Code = 'E',
                    Name = "Erase",
                    Description = "Erase The MCU Chip By Page"
                },
                new SelectableViewModel
                {
                    Code = 'D',
                    Name = "Detect",
                    Description = "Detect The MCU Flash",
                },
                new SelectableViewModel
                {
                    Code = 'P',
                    Name = "Programming",
                    Description = "Programming The MCU Chip By Hex File",
                },
                new SelectableViewModel
                {
                    Code = 'V',
                    Name = "Verify",
                    Description = "Verify The Downing Code",
                },
                new SelectableViewModel
                {
                    Code ='L',
                    Name = "Lock",
                    Description = "Lock The Code To Protect The MCU",
                }
            };
    }
```

So how should I change this into multiple language?

Comment: How many `ItemControl` will  your application have?

Comment: I have only this one in the code I post

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would recommend you to change your localization engine.
There are a lot of different ways.
There is the simplest variant:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299436/WPF-Localization-for-Dummies

Also, this tool will help you to manage your resources files:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ResXManager

And the answer to your question:
If you want to localize your model, you should create it using resources dictionary but not hard coded strings.
It's quite easy if you implement your localization engine like in mentioned 
article.

```
{
return new ObservableCollection<SelectableViewModel>
    {
        new SelectableViewModel
        {
            Code = 'E',
            Name = YourResourcesProject.Resources.Erase,
            Description = YourResourcesProject.Resources.EraseTheMCUChipByPage
        },
        new SelectableViewModel
        {
            Code = 'D',
            Name = YourResourcesProject.Resources.Detect,
            Description = YourResourcesProject.Resources.DetectTheMCUFlash
        },
        new SelectableViewModel
        {
            Code = 'P',
            Name = YourResourcesProject.Resources.Programming,
            Description = YourResourcesProject.Resources.ProgrammingTheMCUChipByHexFile
        },
        new SelectableViewModel
        {
            Code = 'V',
            Name = YourResourcesProject.Resources.Verify,
            Description = YourResourcesProject.Resources.VerifyTheDowningCode
        },
        new SelectableViewModel
        {
            Code ='L',
            Name = YourResourcesProject.Resources.Lock,
            Description = YourResourcesProject.Resources.LockTheCodeToProtectTheMCU
        }
    };
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How should I change `private void btn_LanguageSetting_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` method if I would like to do it in this way?

Comment: You should change CurrentUICulture. It's described in the article.
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU");

Comment: I tried ` var currentLanguage = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture == System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru") ?
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture == System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en")
                : System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");`  in `btn_LanguageSetting_Click` method, it has syntax error with: `member 'CultureInfo' cannot be used like a method`, how should I do?

Comment: What are you going to achieve?
Why do you need this variable?
var currentLanguage  = ...

Comment: Click the button to change the language.

Comment: Do you want to change the localization of your app immediately after click?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150011/discussion-between-valera-scherbakov-and-barrylib).

Answer (score 0):

Don't change anything...make your collection of SelectableViewModel into a XML and change the CreateData to load it into the localized version - you can either have a file for each language or mix all together

Answer (score 0):

20 lines of code....as you want - cannot more explicit than that :-(

```
   public class Selectable(View)Model
    {

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

///you can deserialize your view model directly
private ObservableCollection<SelectableViewModel> CreateData()
{
   return new ObservableCollection<SelectableViewModel>( Deserialize( file_name_code_lang.xml, SelectableViewModel) );
}

//    or going through a model class
private ObservableCollection<SelectableViewModel> CreateData()
    {
       return new ObservableCollection<SelectableViewModel>( Deserialize( file_name_code_lang.xml, SelectableModel ).Foreach(p=> new SelectableViewModel(p) );
    }

static public object Deserialize(string filePath, Type objType)
    {
        object objToDeserialize = null;

        XmlTextReader xmlReader = null;
        XmlSerializer xmls = null;

        try
        {
            xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(filePath);
            xmls = new XmlSerializer(objType);

            objToDeserialize = xmls.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            BusinessLogger.Manage(err);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            xmls = null;
            xmlReader.Close();
        }

        return objToDeserialize;
    }
```

Comment: This is method to Deserialize xml file, what do I suppose to do to localize the application for the itemscontrol.

Comment: do the same for your SelectableViewModel

Comment: My `SelectableViewModel` did not change the language when I call `btn_LanguageSetting_Click`

Comment: well, i do not understood...in btn_LanguageSetting_Click, call Deserialize with a corresponding file, reload your collection of SelectableViewModel - that's done

Comment: I still have no clue what you are doing here.

Comment: Sorry, but I give up. This is just a sample code...adapt it !